# nghttp2 asio connecting to Apple Push Notification times out

Tags: c++, apple-push-notifications, boost-asio, http2, nghttp2

I'm using nghttp2_asio to connect to the Apple Push Notifications developer service. I'm trying to follow the [APN guide as written](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1):

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; do
>   not repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time

So I'm trying to write it in a way that the connexion doesn't time out. However, my connexion does time out after about a minute. I see sending a PING frame for non nghttp2_asio but not for the asio version as Apple says also:

> You can check the health of your connection using an HTTP/2 PING
>   frame.

How can I keep connected to APN?

**Code**

```
#include <nghttp2/asio_http2_client.h>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp>

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#define LOG_EASY( STREAM ) std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << STREAM << std::endl;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_context( boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23 );

    std::string hostname( "https://api.development.push.apple.com:443" );

    // The context options
    ssl_context.set_options( boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
            boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use );

    // Now put it up
    ssl_context.use_private_key_file( "/home/mike/dev/cpp/sw/run/certs/apn.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem );
    ssl_context.use_certificate_file( "/home/mike/dev/cpp/sw/run/certs/apn.crt", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem );

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    nghttp2::asio_http2::client::configure_tls_context( ec, ssl_context );
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error( ec ); // Throw as necessary

    // Make the new session
    nghttp2::asio_http2::client::session session( io_service,
            ssl_context,
            "api.development.push.apple.com",
            "443" );

    // On connect callberk
    session.on_connect( [ &session, &hostname ]( boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint ) {
        LOG_EASY( "Connected!" );

        // Error cheek
        boost::system::error_code e;

        // Generate a crazy filename
        boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();

        // Header merp
        nghttp2::asio_http2::header_map headers;
        headers.emplace( "apns-id", (nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value){ boost::uuids::to_string( uuid ), false } );
        headers.emplace( "apns-expiration", (nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value){ "0", false } );
        headers.emplace( "apns-priority", (nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value){ "10", false } );
        headers.emplace( "apns-topic", (nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value){ "com.company.App-Topic", false } );

        // Send a test push
        const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::request *request = session.submit( e,
                    "POST",
                    hostname+"/3/device/129a46cbac12d8c523aaf8a1758d07f0fc8b291c776aed4a7dc6f1535be1521e",
                    "{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"Hello\" } }",
                    headers );

        boost::asio::detail::throw_error( e ); // Throw as necessary

        // Now hook
        request->on_response( []( const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::response &response ){
            LOG_EASY( "response received! Status code: " << response.status_code() );

            response.on_data( []( const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len ) {
                LOG_EASY( "Response length: " << len );
                LOG_EASY( std::string( (const char *)data, len ) );
            } );
        } );

        // On push
        request->on_push( []( const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::request &push ){
            LOG_EASY( "push request received!" );

            push.on_response( []( const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::response &res ){
                LOG_EASY( "push response received!" );

                res.on_data( []( const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len ) {
                    LOG_EASY( std::string( (const char *)data, len ) );
                });
            });

        } );

        // On close
        request->on_close( []( uint32_t error_code ){
            LOG_EASY( "Request close: " << error_code );
        } );
    } );

    // On error kerlbook
    session.on_error( []( const boost::system::error_code &error ) {
        LOG_EASY( error.message() );
    } );

    // Run the servace
    io_service.run();
}
```

**Output**

```
main(int, char**)::<lambda(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)>: Connected!
main(int, char**)::<lambda(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)>::<lambda(const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::response&)>: response received! Status code: 200
main(int, char**)::<lambda(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)>::<lambda(const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::response&)>::<lambda(const uint8_t*, std::size_t)>: Response length: 0
main(int, char**)::<lambda(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)>::<lambda(const nghttp2::asio_http2::client::response&)>::<lambda(const uint8_t*, std::size_t)>: 
main(int, char**)::<lambda(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::iterator)>::<lambda(uint32_t)>: Request close: 0
main(int, char**)::<lambda(const boost::system::error_code&)>: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the developer of nghttp2 this is now a feature without having to modify the above code it works.

https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/issues/847